# How to close BottomSheetDialogFragment() from another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, inside that class, I have a fragment container, one of them is `LoginFormFragment`, when successfully login in login fragment, I want the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` closed or dismissed. How?

I'm calling the `bottomsheet` from `MainFragment` and this is how I call it:

```
bottomSheetFragment = AuthBottomSheetFragment()
bottomSheetFragment.show(parentFragmentManager, bottomSheetFragment.tag)
```

In `LoginFormFragment`, I tried to call `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to dismiss the dialog, but it doesn't work:

`private val bottomSheet = AuthBottomSheetFragment()`

when login success:

`bottomSheet.dialog?.dismiss()`

Comment: please add a more detailed code, for instance, your main container and where exactly are you calling bottomsheet from

Comment: i have just added where im calling the bottomsheet from

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragments